# Grok pattern for logstash configuration file

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, logstash-grok

Below is the log which is being generated from spring application and trying to create custom grok filters

```
{"@timestamp":"2021-02-19T10:27:42.275+00:00","severity":"INFO","service":"capp","pid":"19592","thread":"SmsListenerContainer-9","class":"c.o.c.backend.impl.SmsBackendServiceImpl","rest":"[SmsListener] [sendSMS] [63289e8d-13c9-4622-b1a1-548346dd9427] [synemail] [ABSENT] [synfi] [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] [N/A] [N/A] [End Method]"}
```

Output expecting after applying the filters is

```
id   => "63289e8d-13c9-4622-b1a1-548346dd9427"
token1   => "synemail"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I'd recommend parsing the text as a json to extract the "rest" value into a field. Then, assuming that the "rest" value has always the same structure, and in particular that the id is always within the third `[]` block and the token always within the fourth `[]`, this grok rule should work for you

```
\[%{DATA}\] \[%{DATA}\] \[%{DATA:id}\] \[%{DATA:token1}\]
```

Note that you can always test your grok rules in Kibana, using the Grok debugger: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/7.11/xpack-grokdebugger.html

And if you don't want to apply grok to the json directly without preprocessing it, this is the rule:

```
"rest":"\[%{DATA}\] \[%{DATA}\] \[%{DATA:id}\] \[%{DATA:token1}\]
```

**Update based on the OP comments:**

Assuming that the field you're parsing is "message" and that its value is a json as a text with escaped quotes, the full configuration of the Logstash grok filter something like:

```
grok {
   match => { "message" => '\"rest\":\"\[%{DATA}\] \[%{DATA}\] \[%{DATA:id}\] \[%{DATA:token1}\]' }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!! i am new to GROK and not able to apply filter insider a filter. reading the rest is critical but i am not able to parse it and i believe need to apply conditions on the rest after reading that, and rest always comes in same format. could you please help me on this..

Comment: If rest always comes in the same format, the two grok rules above are what you are looking for. I will update my answer with the full grok filter configuration

Comment: i have done the changes as you suggested but it didn't parse it properly. please find the filter i have used and  i am seeing in parsing error in log stash console

filter{
    grok {
   match => { "<name_of_the_field_with_the_flat_json>" => '"rest":"\[%{DATA:class}\] \[%{DATA:method}\] \[%{DATA:id}\] \[%{DATA:token1}\] \[%{DATA:token2}\] \[%{DATA:token3}\] \[%{DATA:token4}\] \[%{DATA:token5}\] \[%{DATA:token6}\] \[%{DATA:token6}\]' }
}
  }

Comment: {
       "message" => "{\"@timestamp\":\"2021-02-20T15:57:06.807+00:00\",\"severity\":\"INFO\",\"service\":\"cp\",\"trace\":\"\",\"span\":\"\",\"parent\":\"\",\"exportable\":\"\",\"pid\":\"16424\",\"thread\":\"Ser-15\",\"class\":\"c.o.c.nd.impl.Smpl\",\"rest\":\"[com.on.cp.liss.SmsListener] [sendSMS] [52a3abe4-dc00-49bf-95da-16726200ee59] [synemail] [ABSENT] [synfi] [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] [N/A] [N/A] [End]\"}\r",
          "type" => "syslog",
          "port" => 54088,
    "@timestamp" => 2021-02-20T15:57:20.186Z,
          "tags" => [
        [0] "_grokparsefailure"
    ],
}

Comment: It seems the text to parse in your comment has the quotes escaped, which was not the case in your original question. If you don't want to sanitize your text before parsing it with grok, you need to include the escape \ into your grok rule - i.e., `\\"rest\\":\\"\[%{DATA}\]  etc.`

Comment: i have tried as you suggested but still seeing the same problem. can you please paste the complete grok filter

Comment: I've updated my answer but please consider that your original question has been answered already. As I suggested, you can validate your grok rule first by using the grok debugger in Kibana, against some real inputs. If the grok rule seems correct but you still get Logstash errors, you should either show us your full grok filter configuration, or validate your hypothesis that the "message" value has always the same pattern.

Comment: Any luck, @user3907963? Was the question answered? :)

Comment: Thanks a lot !!  i am able to filter it based on your last suggestion..